# Meteor collection.update causes session variable to be reset

Tags: meteor

What's happening is, when .addGuest is clicked everything works except that meal becomes undefined and my view is broken.  Everything that is revealed by {{#if owner}} does not get displayed and I get this error in my console.

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'owner' of undefined
at Object.Template.menu_details.helpers.owner     (http://localhost:3000/client/workflow/meal_details_page/meal_details.js
```

There are no errors on my server console and all data being passed is stored in my db.  Somehow Session.get('current_meal') is losing it's data on the invite method.  I had commented it out of the event handler and everything else works perfectly.

Thanks

this is my Query that is getting lost...

```
  meal: function () {
return MealModel.findOne(Session.get('current_meal'));
 },
 owner: function() {
var meal = MealModel.findOne(Session.get('current_meal'));
return meal.owner === Meteor.userId();
},
```

here is my method in the server

```
      invite: function (options) {
    check(options, {
      mealId: String,
      firstName: String,
      lastName: String,
      email: String
    });
    var meal = MealModel.findOne(options.mealId);
    if (! meal || meal.owner !== this.userId)
      throw new Meteor.Error(404, "No such meal");
    MealModel.update(options.mealId, {$addToSet: {
      invited: {
        firstName: options.firstName,
        lastName: options.lastName,
        email: options.email
      }}});
  },
```

my Meteor.call function...

```
  invite = function(options) {
Meteor.call('invite', options);
  },
```

and finally, my event handler...

```
  'click .addGuest': function (evt, tmpl) {
var firstName = tmpl.find('.firstName').value;
var lastName = tmpl.find('.lastName').value;
var email = tmpl.find('.email').value;
var meal = Session.get('current_meal');

if (firstName.length && lastName.length && email.length) {
  var id = createGuest({
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email,
    meal: meal._id,
    owner: meal.owner
  });
 invite({
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email,
    mealId: meal._id
  });
};
return false;
},
```

Comment: Search for `Session.set('current_meal'`, where do you use it?

Comment: What you are looking at is basically a post template. I am setting the Session on what would be a posts template.

Comment: I have read in the docs that I need a callback when updating an object.  I don't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that's missing from your question is where you *set* the session variable `current_meal`. You have to be careful with `findOne` because it returns `null` when no documents are found—and that can happen both when there really are no matching documents in the collection, but also if you’re on the client and the matching documents simply haven’t synced to the client yet.

To fix it, find your code that says `Session.set('current_meal', meal)` or similar, and add a check so that it only happens when `meal` isn’t null:

```
if (meal != null)
  Session.set('current_meal', meal);
```

Also, in your `click .addGuest` event handler, check that `meal` is valid like you also check the other values:

```
if (firstName.length && lastName.length && email.length && meal != null) {
```

Comment: Ok. So let me make sure I understand this.  When I update my Object it causes null to be returned to my session variable?  And the solution is to not let Session return null?  That makes sense, but adding verification to my event handler, is that just a safety precaution or is it necessary as well?

Comment: `findOne` can always return null. No matter how careful you are, no matter how sure you are that what you’re looking for really is in the database, you always need to check for the case when `findOne` returns null. That’s why I check for null before assigning the Session variable, just as good practice; and so that  templates depending on `current_meal` don’t rerender. You *also* need to check for null in your handler, even with the earlier check, in case `current_meal` has yet to be defined the first time.